# Is there a explanation of why my form don't update profile info?

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-8

I'm building a project with profiles, and they need to be updated. Currently, i'm trying to finish it's backend, but can't manage to update the data.
Can anyone give me a hint of what is going on? Here's the code:

Routes

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'profile',
    'as' => 'profile.',
    'middleware' => ['auth']
], function () {
    Route::get('/{id}',  [ProfileController::class, 'show'])->name('profile');
    Route::get('/{id}/edit',  [ProfileController::class, 'edit'])->name('profile.edit');
    Route::post('/{id}/edit', [ProfileController::class, 'update'])->name('profile.update');
}
);
```

Controller

```
   public function update(Request $request, User $user)
    {        
        $currentUserId = $user->id;
        $this->validate(request(), [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|exists:users',
            'description' => 'required'
        ]);

        $user->name = request('name');
        $user->email = request('email');
        $user->description = (request('description'));

        $user->update();

        return view('dashboard');   
    }
```

Form(view)

```
    <form action="{{ route('profile.profile.update', $user->id) }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <h2 class="text-2xl font-bold ">Editar Perfil</h2>
                    <p class="my-4 opacity-70">Insira as informações abaixo</p>
                    <p class="my-6">
                    <div class="inline-flex mx-10">
                        <div class="inline-block">
                        <img class="w-32 h-32 mx-auto border border-2 rounded-full border-blackapp" src='{{ Storage::url("$user->id/$user->profilepicture") }}' alt="">
                        <x-input id="profilepicture" class="block w-full mt-1 h-25" type="file" name="profilepicture"  accept="image/*" :value="old('profilepicture')" />
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <p class="my-6">
                    <label class="text-sm font-bold uppercase opacity-70">Nome</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" value="{{$user->name}}" required class="w-full p-3 mt-2 mb-4 border-2 rounded bg-slate-200 border-slate-200 focus:border-slate-600 focus:outline-none">
                    <label class="text-sm font-bold uppercase opacity -70">Email</label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" value="{{$user->email}}" required class="w-full p-3 mt-2 mb-4 border-2 rounded bg-slate-200 border-slate-200 focus:border-slate-600 focus:outline-none">
                    <label class="text-sm font-bold uppercase opacity-70">Descrição</label>
                    <input type="text" name="description" value="{{$user->description}}" required class="w-full p-3 mt-2 mb-4 border-2 rounded bg-slate-200 border-slate-200 focus:border-slate-600 focus:outline-none">
                
                    <input type="submit" class="px-6 py-3 my-2 font-bold duration-300 ease-in-out rounded cursor-pointer text-newwhite bg-blackapp" value="Editar">
                </form>
```

When submiting,the page just reloads and nothing gets changed!
There's no errors showing, but my user data is not updated.

Sorry for any rookie mistake, i'm currently on the proccess of learning. Thanks for your time!

Comment: have you tried to `php artisan route:clear`?

Comment: and your form missing `@csrf` token

Comment: Can you expand on what "can't use post method" means? Can't use it how? What actually happens? Do you get 404, 405 or some other error?

Comment: after inserting csrf and clearing routes, i submit the form but it just reloads the page, and nothing happens

Comment: @M.Eriksson i was getting 419 before applying b4zb0z suggested changes, now there's no error anymore, just does nothing

Comment: it should just reload since you have `return back();` which would return you to the form again after submission. i suggest rendering validation errors into your blade since it might be the cause now. https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors

Comment: and maybe add `dd($request)` into the controller method so you can verify that to form submission is actually passing through

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to call the `request()` function, you already have the $request injected.

You have your route set on an `id` with `Route::post('/{id}/edit', [ProfileController::class, 'update'])->name('profile.update');` but you're not using the `id` in your method, but expecting a user. That user is not provided automatically, if you want that, you need to use [route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#route-model-binding).

An example with an automatically injected `User` for your case would be:

```php
Route::post('/{user}/edit', [ProfileController::class, 'update'])->name('profile.update');

//and inside the update method you can now use
public function update(Request $request, User $user)
```

Your use of the `update()` method is not correct, you need to call the `save()` method in order to save the modified attributes or use the `update()` function like in the following example:

```php
$user->update([
    'name' => $request->get('name'),
    'email' => $request->get('email'),
    'description' => $request->get('description'),
])
```

A complete solution to your problem should be something like this:

```php
public function update(Request $request, int $id)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|exists:users',
        'description' => 'required'
    ]);

    $user = User::findOrFail($id);
    $user->name = $request->get('name');
    $user->email = $request->get('email');
    $user->description = $request->get('description');
    
    if(!$user->save()) {
        // throw some exception here
    }

    // return the $user in the view as well
    return view('dashboard', ['user' => $user]);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: A quick mention would be that you should not provide an `id` to your profile routes, but use the currently authenticated user, since you are within the `auth` middleware.